# MAMP Pro: after update to 4 database is empty

Tags: mamp-pro

After Updating from MAMP 3 to 4 all the database is completly empty. In appsolute/MAMP PRO/db there are two folders: mysql with my databases and mysql56 which is nearly empty. How could i get my databases in the new mysql? I cannot dump all my databases.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem ... The reason was that i renamed the old mamp and mamp pro folders before installing the new version. So mamp does not realize that it was an update and created new databases. After deleting the version 4, restoring version 3 completely i tried the update once more and was sucessful. Attention: you have to shut down all servers before installing the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason: I renamed the old mamp and mamp pro folders before installing the new version. So mamp does not realize that it was an update and created new databases.

Solution:

- delete version 4
- restore version 3 completely
- update once more

Attention: you have to shut down all servers before installing the update